# chapterbib package not working on revtex4

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing, revtex, journal-publishing

I am trying to create two separate bibliographies for my article, one for the main part and another for the supplementary part of an article using `chapterbib` package. The below is my minimum working example:

```
%\documentclass{report}
\documentclass[prb,twocolumn,aps,floatfix]{revtex4}  
\usepackage{chapterbib} 
\begin{document}

\include{section1}

\include{section2}

\end{document}
```

where chapter1.tex and chapter2.tex include relevant text followed by

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Ref} % for section1.tex
%\bibliography{RefSupp} % for section2.tex
```

at the end; `Ref.bib` and `RefSupp.bib` are the BibTeX files for the main part and the supplementary part of the article. Now if I replace document class from `revtex4` to `report` i.e. comment line 2 instead of line 1, everything goes well: I get separate bibliographies for separate sections using the following commands:

```
latex mainfile
bibtex section1
bibtex section2
latex mainfile
latex mainfile
```

But I get the error `I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file section1.aux` at steps 2 and 3 if I use the `revtex4` document class. Does anyone have any idea on how to get `chapterbib` to work with `revtex4`? Or perhaps an alternative solution to my problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `\bibliographystyle{plain}` have you tried using something like `\bibliographystyle{aipnum4-1}`. Also try `revtex4-1`.